# Importing a combined p value test module

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to import a module to do a test to combine p values as described in:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.combine_pvalues.html

as:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
results =stats.combine_pvalues([0.099522,0.049951,0.034767,0.025991,0.000402,0.000387,0.000468,0.013807,0.0062,0.040191])
print results
```

However when I run it I get:

```
      1 import scipy.stats as stats
----> 2 results = stats.combine_pvalues([0.099522,0.049951,0.034767,0.025991,0.000402,0.000387,0.000468,0.013807,0.0062,0.040191])
      3 print results
     'module' object has no attribute 'combine_pvalues'
```

Comment: That traceback doesn't match your code...

Comment: I left some out but i've edited it for the full traceback

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are not using the latest version of scipy. Run this command:

```
$python -c "import scipy; print scipy.__version__"
```

and see if you version is 0.15.1. If not, you should upgrade your scipy in order to use function combine_pvalues.